# creata a table in mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a table in my SQL database that I've successfully created. However, i can't seem to get it to work.

I've basically followed the step by step guide on w3 but it still dont work.

Can anyone see what im missing?

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "enigmaPaamelding";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Create database
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE enigmaPaamelding";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Database created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
    }

   // sql to create table
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE BedriftPaameldinger (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   code VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(50),
   reg_date TIMESTAMP
   )";
```

?>

Comment: what is the error that you getting ? are you using LAMP/WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP?

Comment: You can't connect to a non-existing database.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors that i can see. I'm using WAMP

Comment: What error are you getting. I see you created the query string. Did you leave off the code where you make the query?

Comment: well your script is going to fail if the db already exists, you cant create it twice. `ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` will show you this

Comment: if that all your code add another `$conn->query($sql);` at the end

Comment: allright, i can see the error message. So i need to remove the create database in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to select your Database before you create any table in the database the code is here.

```
$conn->select_db ( "enigmaPaamelding");
```

after that you have to run your last $sql variable in sql query this.

```
// Create table
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "table created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }
```

the final code is here:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Create database
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE enigmaPaamelding";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Database created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
    }

   $conn->select_db ( "enigmaPaamelding");
   // sql to create table
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE BedriftPaameldinger (
   id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
   code VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(50),
   reg_date TIMESTAMP
   )";

// Create table
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "table created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select database before creatinng table: call

```
$conn->select_db ( "enigmaPaamelding");
```

After creating database.